# Easily unpack DEB, edit postinst, and repack DEB

Tags: package-management

I'm attempting to install Intel's OpenCL SDK but the DEB files are buggy conversions from RPM (see [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/515680) for the curious).  I need to edit the `postinst` script in the DEB they provide.

How can I take an existing DEB, extract the contents (including the control information), then later repackage the contents to make a new DEB?  I will only edit files, no files will be added or removed.

Comment: the unpacking part can be done from midnight commander (`apt install mc`)— just press enter on a deb file

Answer (score 325, accepted):

The primary command to manipulate deb packages is [`dpkg-deb`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=dpkg-deb&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy&format=html&locale=en).

To unpack the package, create an empty directory and switch to it, then run `dpkg-deb` to extract its control information and the package files. Use `dpkg-deb -b` to rebuild the package.

```
mkdir tmp
dpkg-deb -R original.deb tmp
# edit DEBIAN/postinst
dpkg-deb -b tmp fixed.deb
```

Beware that unless your script is running as root, the files' permissions and ownership will be corrupted at the extraction stage. One way to avoid this is to run your script under [`fakeroot`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=fakeroot&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy&format=html&locale=en). Note that you need to run the whole sequence under `fakeroot`, not each `dpkg-deb` individually, since it's the `fakeroot` process that keeps the memory of the permissions of the files that can't be created as they are.

```
fakeroot sh -c '
  mkdir tmp
  dpkg-deb -R original.deb tmp
  # edit DEBIAN/postinst
  dpkg-deb -b tmp fixed.deb
'
```

Rather than mess with permissions, you can keep the data archive intact and modify only the control archive. `dpkg-deb` doesn't provide a way to do that. Fortunately, deb packges are in a standard format: they're [`ar`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ar&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy&format=html&locale=en) archives. So you can use `ar` to extract the control archive, modify its files, and use `ar` again to replace the control archive by a new version.

```
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
ar p ../original.deb control.tar.gz | tar -xz
# edit postinst
cp ../original.deb ../fixed.deb
tar czf control.tar.gz *[!z]
ar r ../fixed.deb control.tar.gz
```

You should **add a [changelog entry](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#s-dpkgchangelog) and change the [version number](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Version)** if you modify anything in the package. The infrastructure to manipulate Debian packages assumes that if two packages have the same name and version, they're the same package. Add a suffix to the *debian_revision* part at the end of the version number; for sorting reasons the suffix should start with `~`, e.g. `1.2.3-4.1` becomes `1.2.3-4.1~johnjumper1`.

Instead of using shell tools, you can use Emacs. The [`dpkg-dev-el` package](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/utils/dpkg-dev-el) (which is its own upstream as this is a native Debian package) contains modes to edit `.deb` files and to edit Debian changelogs. Emacs can be used interactively or scripted.

Comment: You can also use the `-e` switch of [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) to change the control file: `fpm -e -s deb -t deb ../old.deb`. This will open the control file in your editor.

Comment: btw, `fakeroot bash` and try to issue commands will not work concerning ownership, and the `ar` method is incredbly fast for big deb files!

Comment: Thanks. This was useful. Using `dpkg-deb -R` the modes were kept and `dpkg-deb -b` reset the `uid:gid` of the extracted files to `0:0`. Didn't need fakeroot (I imagine there might be issues if there were set{u,g}id files inside the archive but that wasn't the case in my situation.

Comment: @PSkocik Not just setxid files, also e.g. files and directories under `/etc` or `/var` that need to belong to a specific group.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Is there a way to ensure that the rebuilt package vs original package has the same md5sum?

Comment: @AmaJayJB In useful cases, the rebuilt package cannot have the same md5sum since it has different content. If you want to ensure that it has the same content in the special case when you don't make any edits, the code in my answer doesn't do that, you need to look into reproducible builds.

Comment: @PSkocik How did you confirm that the IDs have been reset?

Comment: Using the ar/tar method described, instead of dpkg-deb, can still result in ownership issues, and thus likely still requires using fakeroot.
Lintian will warn:
`E: dummypackage: control-file-has-bad-owner md5sums user1/user1 != root/root E: dummypackage: control-file-has-bad-owner postinst user1/user1 != root/root E: dummypackage: control-file-has-bad-owner prerm user1/user1 != root/root `

Answer (score 8):

You can use [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) with the `--after-install` option to replace the `postinst` script, like this:

```
fpm -e --after-install ../DEBIAN/postinst.new -s deb -t deb ../old.deb
```

Comment: To install fpm on Debian/Ubuntu: sudo apt-get install ruby-dev build-essential; sudo gem install fpm

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to extract files from a .deb file, 7-Zip is convenient. 7-Zip supports "ar" files for "unpacking only". (No need to rename the file; it opens *.deb as "ar" and shows "data.tar" inside.)

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that the OP specifically asked for "unpack DEB ... and repack DEB". Perhaps you can [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/587814/edit) your post to address that subject, too.