# How to make aptitude recognize Oracle Java as a valid java dependency

Tags: debian, java, aptitude, tomcat

I have Oracle Java 7 on my Debian.

I want to install tomcat server using aptitude, but it keeps trying to install icedtea, and unnecessary java related packages. Is it possible for aptitude to know that I already have Java?

NB: I used `make-jpkg` command to install Java from archive.

Comment: Look into the `equivs` package, that may help.

Comment: make-jpkg should already do that, at least if you installed the resulting `.deb`s. Sounds like a bug somewhere... which packages are you seeing that are requiring openjdk?

Comment: @derobert Yes it was with java, and it's when I try to install `tomcat7`

Answer (score 0):

Edit: an easier method is here at the top, but the stuff about `control` files from the full original answer is still relevant, so I am keeping it below the horizontal rule.

If `make-jpkg` already made an Oracle Java .deb file, you could [extract it, modify its `control` file like below to add `provides` directives, re-pack it, and install the modified deb.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138190/).

---

Original answer:

Using `equivs`, one can create a dummy package which basically acts to make dpkg think something is installed.

A good example of how to start using 'equivs' is written [here](http://shallowsky.com/blog/linux/install/blocking-deb-dependencies.html).

> Officially you should start with `equivs-control <:pkgname>` which
>   will create a file `pkgname` in the current directory. Inside are
>   various fields but you only need eight and can simply delete the rest.
>   Here's approximately what you should end up with for a fictional
>   package `pkgname`:

```
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 3.9.2

Package: pkgname
Version: 1:42
Maintainer: Your Name <your@email.address>
Architecture: all
Description: fake pkgname to block a dumb dependency
```

To do this for Oracle Java, and make it act as a substitute for openjdk (which it appears is a dependency of `icedtea-netx` in sid, which I use), I think you need to set the `provides:` entry in the dpkg configuration. So your control file would look something like:

```
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 3.9.2

Package: oracle-java
Version: 7u181-2.6.14-1
Maintainer: Joe Bob <your@email.address>
Architecture: all
Description: dummy Java package to let the system know Oracle JDK is OK to use
Provides: openjdk-7-jdk, openjdk-7-jre, openjdk-7-jre-headless
```

Note the addition of the last line. If I could do colored text in markdown, I'd color it red for emphasis.

Then, according to the blog post linked above:

> Having done this, all you need do is issue the command `equivs-build path-to-pkgname` (preferably from the same directory) and you get a fake deb to install with `dpkg -i`. Say goodbye to the dependency.

For details on the `provides` directive, see:
https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#virtual-packages-provides

Note that I'm not sure which version of debian you're using, so I don't know if OpenJDK 7, 8, or something else is dependent on icedtea.
You should probably install IcedTea at the very least, since I don't think Oracle's JDK has a web plugin. But if you wanted, and you were certain it wouldn't break anything, you could add icedtea as 'provided', too. The package name is (I think - it depends on your Debian release) `icedtea-7-plugin`.