# Install NSIS on SLES zLinux

Tags: wine, cross-compilation, sles, os390

I need to install NSIS (http://nsis.sourceforge.net) on corporate zLinux server (SLES 11 SP 3 on z/OS machine).

Here are the inputs:

1. I have root
2. I don't have compilers there (gcc or g++) and I doubt I can get them installed
3. I don't have support from any other admins (on the project my primary responsibility is development, and because of lack of resources I have to do Linux set up myself)

So, my options are:

1. Find NSIS binary rpm for SLES on s390x platform - probability close to 0
2. Set up some other PC machine with compiler and cross-compile - probability close to 0.001 as I never had a deal with compilers and cross compiling
3. Find Wine binary rpm and after install transfer NSIS MS Windows binaries to zLinux machine - probability close to 0.01% as seems Wine also not popular application for Linux on z/OS platform **<== It was a mistake Wine requires Intel processor, it can not run on zLinux**

Any help is highly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

```
file /bin/ls
/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit MSB executable, IBM S/390, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.4, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No guarantees, but you could try Debian's s390x `nsis` binaries. See https://packages.debian.org/nsis for the packages themselves (try various vintages, I don't know what versions of SLES match the libraries on Debian) and [Easily unpack DEB, edit postinst, and repack DEB](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138188/easily-unpack-deb-edit-postinst-and-repack-deb) for instructions on unpacking the packages without using Debian tools.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was able to find binary RPM earlier and it requires glibc6, which not installed on machine, and so on.. Lots of dependencies, which yum can not handle automatically. For now I gave up, it's beyond my possibilities.