# Problem installing ZoneMinder from jessie-backports under Debian 8

Tags: debian, apt, configuration, dpkg

Starting from a stable Debian 8 installation I did the installation steps in these links:

https://zoneminder.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installationguide/debian.html
https://wiki.zoneminder.com/Debian_8_64-bit_with_Zoneminder_1.29.0_the_Easy_Way

But here's what happens:

Add jessie-backports:

```
# vi /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main
```

Begin install:

```
# apt-get update

# apt-get install zoneminder
...
Preparing to unpack .../zoneminder_1.29.0+dfsg-1~bpo8+1_armel.deb ...
Unpacking zoneminder (1.29.0+dfsg-1~bpo8+1) ...
...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of zoneminder:
zoneminder depends on javascript-common; however:
Package javascript-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package zoneminder (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
...
Errors were encountered while processing:javascript-common
zoneminder
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling javascript-common (and a LOT of other measures) to no avail.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: "Errors were encountered while processing:javascript-common" ... you need to show those errors, you omitted them from your log. Full output from `dpkg --configure -a` would probably work too.

Comment: Nothing omitted - no other errors were displayed by apt-get or dpkg.

Comment: `dpkg --configure -a` doesn't display anything.

Comment: that is odd, because the final error message says something went wrong configuring javascript-common. Try running apt-get install zoneminder again. And give the full output (unless you really have to omit something, e.g., for security) if it's failing still.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help, much appreciated. I was finally able to track this down to a post-install script for javascript-common (dependency of ZoneMinder) that was assuming apache 2.4 (still running apache 2.2 here). With a bit of hacking on the script it finally installed.

Comment: You can accept your own answer (using the checkmark); that will indicate that this question has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Answering because I had the same issue and had to research exactly which incompatibility existed.  Downloaded and extracted the [package](https://packages.debian.org/en/jessie/all/javascript-common/download), commented out entire if..fi block referencing apache2_invoke in postinst, postrm, and prerm, then repackaged the .deb to install with dpkg as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138188/easily-unpack-deb-edit-postinst-and-repack-deb).  The only downside to the repackage is that I may have to remember to delete config files and symlinks if necessary.

Other relevant links:

[Apache 2.4 notes explaining how to parse the new commands wrt packaging](https://wiki.debian.org/Apache/PackagingFor24)

[Notes comparing 2.2 and 2.4 function with apache2_invoke](https://wiki.debian.org/Apache2Transition#Should_we_support_a_transitional_fallback_configuration_which_allows_web_apps_to_work_with_both_2.2_and_2.4_packages)