# How to install wpasupplicant, when there is package libnl-genl-3-200 & libnl-route-3-200 not installed?

Tags: networkmanager, wpa-supplicant

Note: I do not have network manager install. To install it, I require wpasupplicant. This means I have to use my mobile phone to download necessary packages, and transfer it via pendrive using OTG.

I have installed Debian 10 buster. Unfortunately no desktop environment installed, no network manager installed.

It's been more than 30 hours and I trying to connect my laptop to the Internet.

Note: I don't have Ethernet port. I use Tp-link TL-WN722N wifi receiver to connect to WiFi. No desktop environment installed.

The ultimate goal is to install wpasupplicant. So that I can install network-manager and use Internet. I have manually installed several deb packages and firmware offline so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see here: https://packages.debian.org/en/buster/wpasupplicant wpasupplicant depends on those packages mentioned in your headline. You could manually download those files.
Installing packages without installing their dependencies could probably break your system, but it's possible using dpkg as you can read here: https://askubuntu.com/q/74523/196781
- Also there is  a way to extract https://packages.debian.org/en/buster/wpasupplicant and change its control file to have less dependencies and repack it again. Going that way you could install it with apt-get. But I'm not sure what your system will do in case of the need to use the default dependencies which then will not be available due to being not installed. [Easily unpack DEB, edit postinst, and repack DEB](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138188/easily-unpack-deb-edit-postinst-and-repack-deb)

Comment: I have installed wpasupplient & network manager. But when I try "sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid Bond key Bond007" to connect to my wifi, I get this error "Error for wireless request "Set Encode" (8B2A) : invalid argument "Bond007".